# How to use i18n (localization) in Parse Server, inside a cloud code function?

Tags: parsing, parse-platform, localization, parse-server

I am trying to localize a push notification text while inside a Parse Cloud function and after many tries I was not able to have working solution. Is there a way to localized text inside a Parse Server cloud function?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So, for anyone looking for a solution, I used the following library: [i18n-node](https://github.com/mashpie/i18n-node).

Then in the cloud code (I am using Typescript):

```
import i18n from 'i18n';

//... other imports

i18n.configure({
    locales:['en', 'it'],
    directory: __dirname + '/locales'
});
```

And then inside a cloud function is possible to run:

```
i18n.__({phrase: "Hey, well done!", locale: locale}
```

Where locale can come from the request or, in my case, from the user's device language preference.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, and solve it with UTF-8 encoding before sending the notification.

npm package: [**UTF8**](https://www.npmjs.com/package/utf8)

### Usage:

```
var utf8 = require("utf8");


// encode before sending the text
text = utf8.encode(text);
```